# Windows Server 2019 remote users stuck in a black screen

Tags: windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-services, remotefx

So we have 2 virtually identical servers that are hosted somewhere else . Ever since we moved to these new servers in January we noticed periods when one of these servers would become stuck on a black screen when trying to connect with the Remote Desktop App. When that happened we would just try to close and open the connection until the it loaded the lock screen of Windows where you input the name and password of the user. Sometimes randomly clicking on the black screen would help and the login screen would appear normally

We thought it was some sort of RDP virtual display driver problem so we would check for windows updates and install them which would sometimes help but the problem would always pop up again.

Not everyone gets stuck at the black screen just a few, admins are not immune to this issue .

In Event viewer I noticed the follwing errors in RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS

> 'Failed CreateVirtualChannel call on this Connections Stack' in CUMRDPConnection::CreateVirtualChannel at 2498 err=[0xd0000001]

> 'Connection doesn't support logon error redirector' in CUMRDPConnection::GetLogonErrorRedirector at 4179 err=[0x80004001]

> 'Failed GetConnectionProperty' in CUMRDPConnection::QueryProperty at 2884 err=[0x80004001]

These errors appear at every single connection whether it is successful or not

People online say to disable RemoteFX in group policy editor, I followed instructions from this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/cs-CZ/627f1c9f-fa4a-47fe-9ae2-7e467d79b91d/rds-2016-remotefx-killing-connections?forum=winserverTS) but the error still shows up in logs

I also noticed the following Warnings in logs but Im not sure what to do with them

> TCP socket READ operation failed, error 64

> TCP socket WRITE operation failed, error 64

> RDP_TCP: An error was encountered when transitioning from StateUnknown in response to Event_Disconnect (error code 0x80070040).

They also appear on every single connection that takes place

We use these servers to create remote sessions on them, we dont use them to host remote apps and connect to the from somewhere else